# What is a web framework and how frontend and backend related to web framework?

Tags: web, web-development-server

What is a web framework and how are frontend and backend related to a web framework? Are these web framework (Django, flask etc..) work at the frontend or at the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly ***Framework***... we can understand this in this way that if there is a person who made bricks. He made the first brick according to measurements like height and width length and he has to make 100 bricks so he made a box of the same height, length, and width instead of doing measurements again and again, and that box is called a framework.
***Framework is a collection of tools designed to help create your projects so you don't need to start from scratch.***

Similarly, a web framework or web application framework helps build web applications.

There are two types of web-framework:

***1. Server-side/Backend***

***2. Client-side/Frontend***

The ***frontend*** of a website is the part that is presented to the user, the parts you see and interact with when browsing the web.
The ***backend*** is the technology behind that presentation layer that makes everything work, i.e. the server, application, and database.

Basically ***Django*** ***is a backend framework but it is both frontend and backend.***

But ***Flask*** ***is backend framework***.